# how to create this class

Tags: vb.net, xsd

I have a class created from an XSD file in vb.net2010

```
Partial Public Class responseOperation

    Private attributeField() As attribute

    Public Property attribute() As attribute()
        Get
            Return Me.attributeField
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As attribute())
            Me.attributeField = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

how do i instantiate or fill up attribute property where attribute class is given as

```
Partial Public Class attribute

    Private nameField As String

    Private valueField As String

    Public Property name() As String
        Get
            Return Me.nameField
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.nameField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property value() As String
        Get
            Return Me.valueField
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.valueField = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

when i run

```
 xml_req_obj.attribute(0).value = "abcd"
 xml_req_obj.attribute(0).name =  "efg"
```

I get runtime error as im assigning something to a class that is not created

This seems like a trivial task 
If some can tell me how can I create this object and pass data to attribute property that would be wonderful

Thankyou
Hansen

Answer (score 0):

You are not instantiating the array or array items.

Try

```
Private attributeField() As attribute = New attribute(20)
```

and

```
xml_req_obj.attribute(0) = New Attribute()
xml_req_obj.attribute(0).value = "abcd"
xml_req_obj.attribute(0).name =  "efg"
```